# Multicast eventing with UPnP

Tags: multicast, upnp

I am implementing the multicast eventing feature in a Java environment. However I could not find any other implementations to test with. Does anyone know of a stack supporting multicast eventing, in that it can offer a device with a service that sends multicast events?

I have looked at the MS implementation and some open source stuff on git hub and sourcefore, but could not find anything useful. The language is relatively irrelevant, as long as I can get it to work ;)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Multicast as in "specifically IP multicast" or generally any "one to many" event distribution, regardless of the transport layer? (like some kind of publish-subscribe architecture)

Comment: Specifically IP multicast. As specified in section 4.2 of the UPnP 1.1 spec http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is quite outdated, but you can try [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/)

It's a UPNP software stack that you install on your computer and it acts like a real multimedia device (e.g. TV). You can test and send commands to it and also you can listen to the UDP packets that it sends in the network, so that you can write your program for the UPNP protocol.

If I got your question correctly, I think XBMC software can be used as a device with services that can send multicast messages.